# nginx proxy pass to standalone application

Tags: 404, nginx, ubuntu

I'm trying to use  pass traffic which is going to `www.example.com/subfolder` to a standalone application running on the same machine. Here is what I have:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location /loc {

                proxy_pass "https://127.0.0.1:8080";
        }

        location /loc1 {

                proxy_pass "https://127.0.0.1:8081";
        }

        location /loc2 {

                proxy_pass "https://127.0.0.1:8082";
        }

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

}
```

Visiting `www.example.com/loc` after running nginx -s reload returns a 404. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Lets get the easy stuff out of the way.  Have you restarted nginx after making configuration changes to it?

Comment: Does visiting `http://www.example.com/` show the correct `index.html` file from your server?

Comment: Have you tried `location /loc/` (including the trailing slash)?  Some of the examples I'm finding use the trailing slash: https://www.liaohuqiu.net/posts/nginx-proxy-pass/

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify. Yes I've restarted nginx, index.html is showing up as expected, I will try with the trailing slash in case that helps. EDIT: trailing slash didn't change anything.

Comment: The example I linked to doesn't have quotes around the URLs.  If that doesn't make a difference, then I'm out of ideas.   I'm sure there is somebody here that knows more about nginx than I do that can help.

Comment: Visiting `www.example.com/loc` will proxy pass to `https://127.0.0.1:8080/loc` as you are not changing the URI - is that what the stand-alone application expects?

Comment: @RichardSmith That is *not* what the stand-alone application expects. Should I be using a rewrite rule instead? Additionally, ```location /panel {
                #Pass traffic through.
                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        }``` The above code now returns something along the lines of "Communication to backend lost, please check your connection.
This application has encountered an error and cannot continue.", rather than a 404. The primary web page at `example.com` and the standalone web page continue to function.

Comment: I would suggest a trailing `/` on both the `location` and the `proxy_pass` to get the correct rewrite. Are your stand-alone applications accessible over `https` or should you be using `http` in the `proxy_pass`? Many stand-alone applications are very difficult to force into a subfolder, and `nginx` may not be able to fix it.